# D3.js redraw graph on button click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to redraw the D3.js graph on button click? I'm getting data from my Python Flask server as json from `http://127.0.0.1:5000/json`.  Here is my poor attempt:

```
var height = 1000;
var width = 1000;
var color = d3.scale.category10();
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(120)
    //.linkStrength(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/json";
function drawGraph(data){

    force
        .nodes(data.graph.nodes)
        .start();

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(data.graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.group);
        })
        .call(force.drag);

    force.on("tick", function () {
        link.attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
            .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
            .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
            .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});

        node.attr("cx", function (d) {return d.x;})
            .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y;});
    });
}

// This initial load works 
d3.json(url, drawGraph);

// The refresh does not
function refreshGraph() {
    d3.json(url, drawGraph);
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Force-Directed Layout</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="force.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="option">
    <input name="updateButton"
           type="button"
           value="Update"
           onclick="refreshGraph()" />
    </div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="force.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what doesn't work? do you get an error or it doesn't redraw?

Comment: @L.A This adds nodes on top of existing graph and graph somehow freezes. It looks like it adds another graph on top, whether I want to redraw it anew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem arises, because you assign `var node` to `.enter()` section of selection. So, when you update your graph, this section is empty, so during `force.on("tick", ...)` you update nothing.

I suggest to rewrite

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.group);
    })
    .call(force.drag);
```

to

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.graph.nodes)

node.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.group);
    })
    // .call(force.drag);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Although there is no need to switch of `.call(force.drag);`